# Xcode 6.1 , Storyboard, Ctrl+Drag doesnt work, not even blue line

Tags: macos, xcode

I just upgraded to XCode 6.1

I started to create a Mac, Cocoa application.

In story board, i put a button on view controller, and tried to CTRL+DRAG it to the source code.

Problem is that it doesn't work, at least i have to see the blue line despite of where im going to drop it, but nothing happens at all and blue line doesnt appear and control stays put :-s

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I realise I'm a bit late, but my solution to this problem was to ensure that the class that interface builder was "dragging to" was the same as the class that it was under: in other words, everything must be in the same class.

For example, if I have classes `A` and `B`, and a storyboard: I would need to ensure that the storyboard is set to a class. If I set it to `A`, it would only connect elements to class `A`, if I set the class to `B`, attempting to connect elements to class `A` would have a blue line but no `Insert Outlet or Action` or `Connect Outlet/Action`.

---

A visual representation:

```
ViewController.swift:

import Cocoa
class FirstClass: NSViewController {
    // some code here
}

class SecondClass: NSViewController {
    // some more code here
}
```

Here we have declared two classes, `FirstClass` and `SecondClass`. If you look at  your blank storyboard (`Main.storyboard` for the purpose of this answer), you should see something similar to as follows:

[image: Normal Main.storyboard look.]

Now, click the window under the View Controller (blank on a new project), and select the tab that looks a bit like a newspaper in the Inspector.

[image: View Controller and class.]

You should see the default class (ViewController) formatted as a placeholder string in the text field for "Class". Attempting to <kbd>Control</kbd>+Drag would not allow you to create an instance of whatever element you're trying to add to either `FirstClass` or `SecondClass`, but only allow it for the class specified, `ViewController` (for some reason I can't screenshot it).

To add an element to `FirstClass`, change the text in the Class field to `FirstClass` (with any luck autocompletion should finish it for you):
[image: As seen]

Now, <kbd>Control</kbd>+Dragging an element from the Interface Builder to `FirstClass` should work, but will not apply to `SecondClass`. Change the custom class name to whichever class suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the button you must see a menu with button actions. Move the cursor over any circle and it will appear a Plus symbol. Select and drag to your source.

[image]

Comment: Hijherran, thanks for your answer. Actually i am aware of that, but my concern is why CTRL+DRAG doesnt work, that weird. I would like to use ctrl+drag as i used to

Comment: OK, but, could you see this menu when you right click?

Comment: yes of course, i see this menu and when i drag circles beside menu items, i can see the blueline. but when i press ctrl and drag a control (buttton), that blue line doesnt appear.

Answer (score 0):

I have not played with Storyboards much.

But I think you need to drag to the viewController.h file rather than the AppDelegate.h

Comment: Yes, you are right and i intend to do that, problem is that the blue line doesn't appear at first place, no matter where i am going to drag it to. Its not only in StoryBoard, i have same problem with xib files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i know its stupid, but i found the problem.

It doesnt work because im connecting to the Mac using VNC :(
It seems connecting to Mac remotely , doesn't reproduce or simulate Keyboard keys and mouse clicks, even though i can see ctrl key goes down on "Keyboard Viewer" when i press ctrl, but something is wrong with VNC that prevent Xcode to act correctly.

I used two different VNC clients and none of them worked, I update this post if i can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

just delete everything inside DerivedData Folder (/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData)

It worked for me :)